# I want to pass multi value in stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql

This is my procedure I want to pass multiple values in `v_supp_list`. So the cursor I mean select query part is returning the rows, whenever I am testing the procedure is returning no rows. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

```
create or replace procedure report_supp_vendregrem
     (v_supp_list in varchar2,
      my_cur out sys_refcursor) as
begin

  open my_cur for
    select a.sup_code,
           a.sup_name,
           a.sup_add1,
           a.sup_Add2,
           a.sup_add3,
           a.sup_pin,
           c.profile,
           lpad(rownum, 4, 0) letter_no,
           b.user_name,
           d.user_desg,
           a.sup_tmp_code,

           decode(e.flag,
                  1,
                  'Sub : Reminder (1) for Renewal of Vendor Registration',
                  2,
                  'Sub : Reminder (2) for Renewal of Vendor Registration',
                  3,
                  'Sub : Reminder (3) for Renewal of Vendor Registration',
                  'Sub : Reminder for Renewal of Vendor Registration') hdr1,
           'Your current vendor registration with ASP will expire / has expired on ' ||
            to_char(a.reg_valid, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ||
            '. Henceforth we may not be in a position to issue' ||
            ' Tender Enquiry to you, until your renewal of registration. A renewal form is enclosed herewith. If you are interested in further renewal of registration' ||
            ' you may please fill up the details as required and submit the same along with the renewal fee of Rs ' ||

            decode(e.flag, 1, 5000, 2, 5000, 3, 5000, 2000) ||
            '/-  in the form of Demand Draft drawn' ||
            ' in favour of "SAIL a/c ALLOY STEELS PLANT" or else we may exclude your name from our registered Vendor List. Please fill up the details as' ||
            ' required & send for renewal to us by ??' body1
      from mm_supplier_mst_t        a,
           mm_sup_profile_t         c,
           aspadmin.user_login_t    b,
           aspadmin.asp_user_master d,
           mm_supp_renew_t          e
     where a.sup_code = c.sup_code
       and a.sup_code = e.sup_code
       and b.user_code = 29
       and b.user_id = d.user_id
       and a.reg_f != 'P'
       and c.profile is not null
          -- and a.reg_valid between v_valid_date and v_valid_date1;
       and e.sup_code in (v_supp_list);
end;
```

Comment: Don't add links, add your code here. To format it add a tab character before every line or 4 spaces.

Comment: Any code you would like to ask about should appear in the question itself.

Comment: so bro any solution @jorge

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Application name is PLSQL Developer  (sql server)

Comment: Doesn't PLSQL Developer work with Oracle only, and not MS SQL Server?

Comment: reference cursors are closed implicitly after end of session so. Use varray instead of cursor.

Comment: Didn't get u @NarasimhaMaiya can u please elaborate

Comment: As per my knowledge values for a cursor or ref cursor in this case will be allocated only when cursor is opened. And de-allocated when you close. If you did't close a cursor and your block execution completes cursor will be closed implicitly. So all the rows will be removed from the cursor memory.Assign cursor value to a  collection and return the same. I think it will solve the problem